# Is it possible to create a MYSQL view where a single field could be populated from two different fields in a table based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, view

I am trying to create a View using certain fields from a single MYSQL table. But in one of the fields in the Table, I need to populate the field from either one field in the table or another field in the same table based on the value of a third field in the table. Is this possible, and if so, how?

To explain, The table contains data from two suppliers. The entries in the table from "Supplier A" store the Account Number in field `CustomerNumber` while the entries in the table from "Supplier B" store the Account Number in field `CustomerAcct`. The view I need to generate needs to list all of the customer orders from both suppliers combined, and populate a single field in the view called `AccountNumber` with either the value from `CustoomerNumber` or `CustomerAcct`, depending on which supplier filled the order.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which column identifies the supplier?

Comment: Yes, you can put expressions into your view definition, but then it won't be an updatable view.

Comment: Why do you want a VIEW, as opposed to simply executing a query?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the "case" function, as in [mysql case](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_case.asp)

```
CASE
    WHEN  Supplier = 'A' THEN customernumber
    ELSE customeraccount
END as accountnumber
```